# Django database query error: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting the following error:

```
"'used_intent' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"
```

My Models are here:

```
class Intents(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    intent = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'intents'

class UsedIntents(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    report_id = models.IntegerField()
    used_intent = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'used_intents'
```

and here are the corresponding lines of code:

```
usedIntentsElement = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('intent')
for element in usedIntentsElement:
    try:
        intentsEntry = Intents.objects.get(intent=element.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
        intentsEntryId = intentsEntry.id
    except:
        # if intent is unknown add it to the database and get the id of the new entry
        intentsEntry = Intents(intent=element.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
        intentsEntry.save()
        intentsEntryId = intentsEntry.id
    usedIntentsEntry = UsedIntents(report_id=int(reportEntryId), used_intent=int(intentsEntryId))
    usedIntentsEntry.save()
```

Does anyone of you have an idea what the cause of this error is?

Comment: You should look into Django ForeignKeys. You try to do them manually but this approach will get very limited very fast. You can read the Django tutorial for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip with the ForeignKeys, now its working!